# Determining the 2 adic divisibility of the totient of a Natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Basically I wanted to determine exactly what the largest power of 2 the totient of a natural number will be divisible by,I'm sure I have done something silly at some point, but that's how it is with direct proofs sadly no dignity spared there:

Anyway this is my attempt thus far,

I began with the Euler product of $n$:

$$E(n)=\prod_{p |n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$$ 
which is equivalent to:

$$E(n)=\frac{\prod_{p |n}(p-1)}{\prod_{p |n}(p)}$$

So likewise the Euler totient function of $n$ can be seen to have proportion to $n$ itself and $n$ divided by it's own radical:

$$\phi(n)=n \cdot \frac{\prod_{p |n}(p-1)}{\prod_{p |n}(p)}$$

And since the radical of a number (denominator of $E(n)$) is a divisor of that number we can assert that:

$\forall n  \in \mathbb N\,$s.t$\,n \gt 1$ $\,\,\exists k \in \mathbb N $ s.t:

$$\phi(n)=k \cdot \prod_{p |n}(p-1)$$

And because $\prod_{p |n}(p-1)$ is a product of  $\omega(n)-1$ even numbers when $n$ is even, and $\omega(n)$ even numbers when $n$ is odd, we can state that:

$$2^{\omega(n)-\frac{1}{2}{((-1)^n+1)})} \,\,\,|\,\,\, \phi(n)$$

And then accounting for the 2-adic order contributed by the other factor of $\phi(n)$, $\frac{n}{\\rad(n)}$:

$$2^{v_{2}(\frac{n}{{rad(n)}})} \,\,\,|\,\,\, \phi(n)$$

Hence collectively we can assert that the 2-adic order for $\phi(n)$ is:

$$v_2(\phi(n))=\omega(n)-\frac{1}{2}((-1)^n+1)+v_{2}(\frac{n}{{rad(n)}})$$
where:

$\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$

$rad(n)$ is the radical of $n$  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order)
$v_p(n)$ is the p-adic order of $n \,\,\,$[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order)

EDIT: In enumerating the concluding result for my attempt as above, it appears that I have indeed made a mistake somewhere here because my conclusion does not hold for all $N$, the actual results only suggests that the following be true:

$$2^{\omega(n)-{((-1)^n+1)}+v_{2}(\frac{n}{{rad(n)}})} \,\,\,|\,\,\, \phi(n)$$

Comment: If you have the $2$-adic valuation of $n$ itself and that of $p-1$ for every odd prime $p$ dividing $n$, you can determine the desired valuation by adding all those valuations and by finally subtracting $1$ if and only if $n$ is even. I doubt that there is a simpler way.

Comment: yes changing to stating I was calculating 2-adic for the totient the quantity as shown certainly is not the 2-adic valuation,  but it is assured that a divisibility holds for that power of 2

Comment: @Peter If I've changed the last part to show you what I mean